# Ruby on rails Model User investor_or_startup:?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am new to rails and I'm creating an application to practice and learn. I have a issue which I don't know how to solve. 
If I generate a model User and I want to include a section in the model where I name it investor_or_startup. When I create the form for a user to fill it out I want the user to only be able to fill in the blank with the word Investor or Startup. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a selector field in your form.

I would share some code but I think as a new rails developers, you should get used to reading and understanding the docs, as that is invaluable.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Comment: Thank you and yes I would prefer to read and learn myself. I appreciate the link and will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a validation in your model for that specific attribute, if it's called `investor_or_startup`, then using `validates` specify this attribute, use the format option, and optionally you can add a message for the user, like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :investor_or_startup, 
    format: { 
      with: /Investor|Startup/, 
      message: 'Two valid options are Investor or Startup' 
    }
end
```

The `with` option inside `format` accepts a regular expression, in this case to check for the specific word `Investor` or (`|`) `Startup`, it's case sensitive, so lowercase letters would make an invalid input. If you want to change to case insenstive then consider adding `i` at the end of your expression, like `/investor|startup/i`.

The message options accepts an string which you can use to display a message for the user.

You can keep reading about this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: Awesome! I will be looking into this and working on implementing it. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Using an enum is a better idea anyways. And you don't need a format validation since the values are simple integers.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way of doing thin in rails would be to add a `role` attribute to your `User` model.  In this case, role replaces start_up_or_investor.  You would start by using a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) to add a field called `role` of type `:integer` to your `users` table.

Next you would add the following line to your `User` model:

```
enum role: [:investor, :start_up]
```

You can read more about `enum` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Finally, you can use a `select_tag` in a [Rails form helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to select one of the `enum` options.  There are many ways to use a `select_tag` with an `enum`.  A quick internet search will reveal many blogs and SO posts on the subject.

Bottom line: I recommend using an `enum` for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a User model and that user could possibly be an investor or a startup. To start off you could add some kind of `"type"` attribute that will query whether the user is a startup or an investor. `User.type #=> "startup"` or `User.type #=> "investor"`. From there you could set up your form_for user  and use a select field that would allow the user to select their value for the type attribute `<%= f.select(:type, ...) %>`
Like Sam suggested, I encourage you to study the rails guides,(particularly form helpers) to help you understand how a form works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding roles to uses is a common programming problem. There are two decent ways to solve this (and many bad ways).

### 1. Use an [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:investor, :start_up]
end
```

An enum is a integer column that maps to specific values. In this case `investor = 0, start_up = 1`.

To create an input based on this you can use the enum mapping:

```
<%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
```

While simple the major limitation is that a user can only ever have one role.

### 2. Setup a [many-to-many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  scope :with_role ->{|*names| joins(:roles).where(name: names) }

  def has_role?(name)
    roles.where(name: name).exist?
  end
end

class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end
```

This lets you add and remove roles from a user seperately and often is a better fit for real world use cases. The [Rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) is an excellent example of this pattern.

To allow a user to select roles you can use a checkbox:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: I would list using stroring a string in the DB as a bad way since the data is not normalized and you're storing tons of duplicates of the strings `investor` and `startup`.